# I need help with training "Drop it" command

Tags: dogs, behavior, training, psychology

I have Labrador and he is such a foodie. I want to teach him "drop it", but everytime he smells or senses treat nearby, he just never holds, catches or fetches anything except to eat the treat. Even though if I am being sneaky for first time that I didn't let him know that treat is nearby, then the second time is same above case. He just want treats, that's all. Help!

Comment: What do you want to teach him? to let drop an item/toy or to let drop a treat?

Comment: Item/toys. Dropping treat for my dog is impossible task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try holding up another toy and saying "drop it". Usually dogs will drop the toy they have for another one. Repeat this a bunch and try it with the one toy. Labs are very smart and will quickly learn. I've done this with my German Shepherd and it worked. As well as my English pointer/coonhound mix.